# Database connection on .mdb slows down over time

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledbconnection

Our application connects to a .mdb-file on Network. All was fine, untill we swapped the Computer from a 32-bit Windows 7 to 64 bit Windows 10. Since this action, connecting to the database through our C# code is getting slower over time. It starts with something lower than 1 second after starting the application. After running the application ca. 8 hours the opening of the database file takes more than 10 seconds, and rising. Ca. every 5 seconds the access database gets connected.

After a restart of the application all is fine. The frequently restart isn't an long term option for our customer. The queries itself are done in some ms and closing is ok, too.
I've seen that the processor usage is only about 10%. Memory i don't know at the moment.

Has anybody an idea why connecting to the database get slowed down over time?

```
public void OpenDb ( string _sOpenString )
{
    this.sFilePathToAccessDb = _sOpenString;
    this.sConnectionString =
        @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=" + this.sFilePathToAccessDb;
    this.oOleDbConnection = 
        new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection( this.sConnectionString);
    this.oOleDbConnection.Open();
}

public void CloseDb()
{
    if (this.oOleDbConnection != null)
    {
        this.oOleDbConnection.Close();
        this.oOleDbConnection.Dispose();
    }
    this.oOleDbConnection = null;
}

public void foo()
{
    OpenDb(@"\\fooserver\databases\bar.mdb");
    //do some stuff
    CloseDb();
}
```

Comment: Is `OpenDb` called just at startup? Or multiple times?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. There are different Access-databases to open on different calls. Hence we call `OpenDb` multiple times

Comment: We know added mode=read to the connection string. looking forward if it helps

Comment: After the software ran for several Days, there were no effect. We found out there a different versions of the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 (old System 12 new System 14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hence after several testing it turned out, that we've installed `Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010` version 14 on the machine. After uninstall this version and install version 12.0 all is fine. Opening a Database on a network drive takes stable 30 ms.